# Removing specific element from a list with JQuery

Tags: jquery, list

i have a dynamic list, which looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="border" id="tl_1">Text1</li>
<li class="border" id="tl_2">Text2</li>
<li class="border" id="tl_3">Text3</li>
</ul>
```

The list can have more items than these three.

When someone clicks on a specific button, i want that e.g. the "tl_2" will be removed from the list. I tried it whith these JQuery commands, but non of them were working:

```
$('#tl_2').remove();
```

or

```
$('li').find('tl_1').remove();
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Show what you tried, it should have worked...

Comment: Note that there is no need to "find" for an element by `id`. `id` is unique

Comment: @Torben, when you say `dynamic`, do you mean the list items are dynamically populated through a request of some kind, possibly *after* the code in your question has run?

Comment: $('#tl_2').remove(); should work (see http://api.jquery.com/remove/). Your second line will work if you replace li with ul: $('ul').find('tl_1').remove();

Comment: It works :( I used the wrong selector to determine the number behind the tl_... Nevertheless is there a function to radically really remove the item and not just set it to "display:none;" ?

Comment: `remove()` does radically remove the item, it does not set its `display` property to `none` as `hide()` does.

Answer (score 19):

You probably have more than one element with the same ID.

You don't have to use ID at all in case you want to remove them by index you can use the `.eq()` method:

```
$("#btnRemove").click(function() {
    $("#myList li").eq(1).remove();
});
```

This will remove the second list item each click.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/wPVHy/).

Answer (score 11):

You probably had some silly mistake, it should work:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
        $('#tl_2').remove();
    });
```

Note that there is no need to "find" for element by id. id is unique.

```
$('li').find('tl_1').remove();  // And you were missing the # anyway...
```

Make sure you have only one element for each `id`. id is like id... You can have only one with the same value.

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not showing us some part of your code as i suspect you are trying to generate that id dynamically, meaning u set it dynamically as well. you have to make sure that there is no 'space' character within the id which will likely mess thing up...

```
$('#tl_2').remove();
```

Works according to jquery documentation. it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You must have an error somewhere else, because what you have [just works](http://jsfiddle.net/AF7jw/).

Please check your error console.

Although your second example should be:

```
$('ul').find('#tl_2').remove(); // but this isn't really needed since we are selecting by id. So just go for the first example which is faster.
```

Comment: Maybe more than one element with same ID, in such case only the first will be removed. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AF7jw/3/)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Good call. Well OP do you have the same ID more than once in the DOM?

Comment: OP won't get notification on your comment here, post comment on his question so he get notification and hopefully answer. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard. Not always, I answered a guy that had page refresh problem, the problem was he had duplicated ids. So not always it will just select the first element...